# Add Gradient to table cell with dynamic height iOS 6

Tags: dynamic, ios6, uitableview, height, gradient

I am applying gradient to cell with dynamic height. But for some cells , gradient is not applied correctly. Here is my code

```
    #pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // If data source is not empty, then return one more cell space.
    // (for displaying the "Loading More..." text)
    if (section == SELLER_FEEDBACK_SECTION){
        if ([self.sellerFeedbacksArray count] == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            DLog(@" self.sellerFeedbacksArray count %d",[self.sellerFeedbacksArray count]);
        return ([self.sellerFeedbacksArray count]);
    }
    else if (section == BUYER_FEEDBACK_SECTION){
        if ([self.buyerFeedbacksArray count] == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            DLog(@" self.buyerFeedbacksArray count %d",[self.buyerFeedbacksArray count]);
        return ([self.buyerFeedbacksArray count]);
    }
    return 0;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UILabel *feedbackTextLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:FEEDBACK_TEXT_TAG];
    [feedbackTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    //Add Gradient to cell background
    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = cell.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[RGBA(212.0, 208.0, 197.0, 1.0)CGColor],(id)[RGBA(166.0, 160.0, 142.0, 1.0)CGColor], nil];
    [cell.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UILabel* feedbackTextLabel;
    UILabel* feedbackByUserLabel;
    UIView* feedbackRatingsView;
    UILabel* feedbackCountNoLabel;
    float height;

    static NSString* CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    RSTapRateView *tapRateView = nil;

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

        tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
        cell.selectionStyle= UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        feedbackCountNoLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 21.0)];
        feedbackCountNoLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        feedbackCountNoLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:SEGOEUI size:14.0];
        feedbackCountNoLabel.tag = FEEDBACK_COUNT_TAG;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:feedbackCountNoLabel];

        feedbackTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        feedbackTextLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:SEGOEUI size:14.0] ;
        feedbackTextLabel.tag = FEEDBACK_TEXT_TAG;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:feedbackTextLabel];
        feedbackTextLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        feedbackTextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
        feedbackTextLabel.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustmentNone;

        feedbackByUserLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
        feedbackByUserLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        feedbackByUserLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:SEGOEUI size:14.0];
        feedbackByUserLabel.tag = FEEDBACK_BY_USER_TAG;
        feedbackByUserLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:feedbackByUserLabel];

        feedbackRatingsView = [[UIView alloc]init];
        feedbackRatingsView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        feedbackRatingsView.tag = FEEDBACK_RATINGS_TAG;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:feedbackRatingsView];

        tapRateView = [[RSTapRateView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(feedbackRatingsView.bounds.origin.x, feedbackRatingsView.bounds.origin.y+13.0f,100.0f ,feedbackRatingsView.bounds.size.height) forStarType:kTinyStar];
        tapRateView.textLabel.hidden = YES;
        tapRateView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        tapRateView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        [feedbackRatingsView addSubview:tapRateView];

    }
    else{
        feedbackTextLabel = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:FEEDBACK_TEXT_TAG];
        feedbackByUserLabel= (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:FEEDBACK_BY_USER_TAG];
        feedbackRatingsView= (UIView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:FEEDBACK_RATINGS_TAG];
        feedbackCountNoLabel= (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:FEEDBACK_COUNT_TAG];
    }

    [self shrinkFontSizeToFit:YES forProductCell:cell];

    Feedback *feedback = nil;
    if (indexPath.section == SELLER_FEEDBACK_SECTION)
    {
        if (indexPath.row < self.sellerFeedbacksArray.count) {
            feedback = [self.sellerFeedbacksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            feedbackTextLabel.text = feedback.feedbackMessage;
            feedbackByUserLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"By %@ on %@",feedback.feedbackGivenBy,feedback.feedbackGivenOnDate];
            feedbackCountNoLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row+1];
            tapRateView.rating = [feedback.feedbackRating intValue];
        }

    }
    else if (indexPath.section == BUYER_FEEDBACK_SECTION)
    {
        if (indexPath.row < self.buyerFeedbacksArray.count) {
            feedback = [self.buyerFeedbacksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            feedbackTextLabel.text = feedback.feedbackMessage;
            feedbackByUserLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"By %@ on %@",feedback.feedbackGivenBy,feedback.feedbackGivenOnDate];
            feedbackCountNoLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row+1];
            tapRateView.rating = [feedback.feedbackRating intValue];
        }
    }
     CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH, 20000.0f);

     CGSize size = [feedback.feedbackMessage sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:SEGOEUI size:14.0] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    [feedbackTextLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN, 10, CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH , MAX(size.height, 44.0f))];

     height = feedbackTextLabel.frame.size.height+feedbackTextLabel.frame.origin.y;
    feedbackByUserLabel.frame = CGRectMake(120, height+5, 190, 21);
    feedbackRatingsView.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, feedbackByUserLabel.frame.origin.y, 100, 30);
    return cell;
}

{
    UILabel *feedbackByUser= (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:FEEDBACK_BY_USER_TAG];

    if (shouldResize) {
        [self resizeFontForLabel:feedbackByUser minSize:MINIMUM_FONT_SIZE];
    }
    else{
        feedbackByUser.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = NO;
  }

}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    if (indexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]-1) {
        return;
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    // Check feedback text height
    Feedback *feedback = nil;
    if (indexPath.section == SELLER_FEEDBACK_SECTION)
    {
        if (indexPath.row < [self.sellerFeedbacksArray count]) {
            feedback = [self.sellerFeedbacksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == BUYER_FEEDBACK_SECTION)
    {
        if (indexPath.row < [self.buyerFeedbacksArray count]) {
            feedback = [self.buyerFeedbacksArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        }
    }

    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH , 20000.0f);

    NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"By %@ on %@",feedback.feedbackGivenBy,feedback.feedbackGivenOnDate];
    CGSize byUserLabelSize = [name sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:SEGOEUI size:14.0] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    NSString *text = [[sellerFeedbacksArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] feedbackMessage];

    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:SEGOEUI size:14.0] constrainedToSize:constraint lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    CGFloat height = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);

    return height + (CELL_CONTENT_MARGIN * 2)+byUserLabelSize.height;

}
```

If row height is large ,gradient is applied 2 times. Also sometimes height for some cell gets changed after scrolling.

Can anybody tell me whats going wrong here ?

Thanks in advance.